# How can I resolve the flex slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

Can anyone help me figure out why am I getting this error?

Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).flexslider is not a function

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.slider').flexslider();

at HTMLDocument.\<anonymous\> (custom-mega-menu.js:4:11492)
at i (custom-mega-menu.js:2:33554)
at Object.fireWith \[as resolveWith\] (custom-mega-menu.js:2:34521)
at Function.ready (custom-mega-menu.js:2:36662)
at HTMLDocument.K (custom-mega-menu.js:2:37059)
```

[the code I have:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOZuL.png)

I tried googling and youtube but I can't find something specific to help figure it out.

Comment: did you load the jquery flexslider plugin?

Answer (score 0):

One can reproduce the problem via

```js
$(".slider").flexslider();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

which is due to the fact that there is a flexslider plugin and you need to include that:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".slider").flexslider();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.2/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

In this second snippet the problem no longer reproduces.